# Wordpress - Search Bar Coding / Plugin Needed

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to add a search bar with customize search in the database,
Like if customer search for cell phone all specification displayed on the same page under the search bar
example link https://z3x-team.com/check-your-phone/

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Ajax Search for WooCommerce.

To install, navigate to Dashboard > Plugins > Add New then search for Ajax Search for WooCommerce, Activate it, and install it.

To configure, Go to WooCommerce > Ajax Search Bar. Here will have multiple settings

1. Search Bar: You can show submit button and also write a placeholder for the search bar.
2. Autocomplete: You can set the limit, also you can checkmark the option which you want to show your user on searches, like Product Image, Price, SKU, Categories, and Details.

Make sure to press the save changes button to apply all the changes.

You can show this search bar in the menu as well as in widgets.

Go to Appearance > Menu > Select Ajax Search Bar from Add menu items.

Click on the save menu button.

Now check it on your page.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/ajax-search-for-woocommerce